# How to pass a value from one lightning component to other component?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

I have two lightning components Opportunity Component and Account component(I added these two components in 2 VF pages respectively). On Opportunity component when I click on lookup icon it will take to **VF page** which has **Account component**. On this page I want to select one account and pass that value to Opportunity component(Account Id value).

Can anyone please help me on this ?

**VF Page : oppPage**

```
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:oppcomponentApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:oppcomponent",
                {objName: 'Opportunity',fieldAPIName:'field__c'},
                "opps",
                function(cmp){
                    console.log("component has been created.");
                }
            );
        })
    </script>
    <div id="opps" />
```

**Component : OppComponent :**

```
<aura:component controller="controller" implements="force:appHostable,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="newOpp" type="Opportunity" access="global" default="{'sobjectType': 'Opportunity'}"/>
<aura:attribute name="Acc ID" type="String[]" />

            <div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
                <ui:button label="Save" press="{!c.saveopp}"
                           />
                <ui:button label="Cancel" press="{!c.cancel}"
                           />
            </div>

<!-- first row -->
            <div>
                <div >
                    <ui:inputText aura:id="opptyName" class="slds-input slds-form-element__label" 
                                  label="Opportunity Name"  value="{!v.newOpp.Name}" required="true"/>
                </div>


                <div>
                    <ui:inputText aura:id="Acc" label="Account ID"   required="true"/>
                        <button type="button" onclick="{!c.goToVfpage}" >
                        <img src="/resource/14978732072/Lookupimg" height="20" width="20"/>
                        </button>

                </div>  

            </div>
            <!-- first row -->
</aura:component>
```

**OppComponentcontroller.js :**

```
({
goToVfpage : function (component, event, helper) {
      var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    if(urlEvent) {
      urlEvent.setParams({
        "url": "/apex/AccPage"
      });

      urlEvent.fire();
    } else {

        window.open("/apex/AccPage", "_blank");
    }

})
```

**VF Page:AccPage**

```
<div id="lightning" />

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:AccountApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:Accountcomponent",
                                       {label: ""}, 
                                       "lightning",
                                       function(cmp) {
                                           //  Do some stuff
                                       }
            );
        });
    </script>
```

**AccountComponent**:

```
<aura:component controller="AccController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" 
                access="global">       
     <aura:attribute name="accountId" type="String" /> 
    <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]" />   

            <div align="center" >
            <ui:button label="Select"/> **<!-- when clicked on this button it should take the selected account id value and add it to the input text Account ID on Opp component before creating opportunity-->**
            <ui:button label="Cancel"/>
                </div>       
        <div >


                <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--fixed-layout  slds-no-row-hover" role="grid">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-text-heading--label ">                                                        
                        <td role="gridcell" class="slds-cell-shrink" scope="col">

                            <label class="slds-checkbox">                      
                            </label>
                        </td> 

                        <th scope="col" aura:id="AccName" aria-label="Account"><span class="slds-truncate" title="Account">Account</span></th>
                        <th scope="col" aura:id="accid" aria-label="Account ID"><span class="slds-truncate" title="Account ID">Account ID</span></th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>        
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.accounts}" var="ac" >         
                <c:AccountRow acc="{!ac}" /> 
            </aura:iteration>
                </table>

        </div>

</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 2):

In lightning there are two ways to pass data from one component to other.

1. Events (component level and application level)
2. Bound expressions

But in your case i think application level events will be helpful.
Hope this will help you.